# RxSwift - Playground execution failed: Couldn't lookup symbols

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, rx-swift, swift-playground

I created a new project and used pods to install `RxSwift`. Then I created a playground and wrote following code :

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import PlaygroundSupport

var name = "hello"
let names = Variable(["Good"])
```

But Console shows this error :

> Playground execution failed:
>
> error: Couldn't lookup symbols:   __T07RxSwift8VariableCACyxGxcfC
>   __T07RxSwift8VariableCMa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this for the `Podfile` instead:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'RxSwiftPlayground' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for RxSwiftPlayground
  pod 'RxSwift', '~> 4.0'
end

post_install do |installer|

    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
    end

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR'] = '$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR'
        end
    end
end
```

Or

1. Delete the line ‘import RxSwift’
2. Clean (Cmd + Shift + K)
3. Build (with error)
4. Put back ‘import RxSwift’

From https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1660

Comment: The steps after **Or** fixed the issue.